# I can install Ubuntu for Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I just wanna know if I can put ubuntu on my Galaxy Mega 6.3. I like how it's works and the difference between android and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The official list of supported devices is available at:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Galaxy Mega 6.3 is unfortunately not in the list.

Comment: link not working